# checking SQL server data formats using numeric() function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to check our MSSQL server for data to verify that it is in Numeric(2,0) format. I am currently using the method below but would like to know how to use the numeric function to check the syntax of the existing data in the database.

Current code or method that I am using:

```
(Case when @variable is not NULL
and @variable like '%.%'
    and blahblah =blahblah
    then 0 else 1 end) as @Variable,
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am currently using 2014

Comment: have you tried the ISNUMERIC() function?

Comment: I have tried the isnumeric() function, but that just verifies it is simply a number correct? I am looking for a method to verify my data is in 111.00 format with two zeros, or simply just 111 with no zeros reported. Not sure isnumeric filters the two different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a numeric function?  The best way to do this is to use `try_convert()` (available in SQL Server 2012+):

```
select (case when try_convert(numeric(2, 0), @variable)) is not null and
                  . . .
             then 0 else 1
        end) as <whatever>
```

Note:  The `is not null` means the conversion is successful.  I'm not sure if that is the logic you really want, perhaps you want `is null`.